# How awkward does "it's really not expensive" sound to you? (adverb placement)

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

A colleague of mine who doesn't speak much English created a meme in which he added (in English)

> Just buy it, it's really not expensive.

Specifically regarding "it's really not expensive," I thought it was a bit awkward, but then I ended up liking it. It sounds like the kind of grammar structure a middle-schooler would use, so it's very casual. I'm thinking of using it on some packaging I'm designing for one of my products. I'd fix the punctuation so it would read

> Just buy it. It's really not expensive.

On one hand, I don't want customers to think I have bad English. But it's also kind of youthful, playful, and humorous.

So my question is how grammatically terrible, if at all, does it sound to you? Could it be forgiven/passed off as informal, conversational language between two friends?

Answer (score 1):

The word "not" is modifying "expensive," not "really expensive" or the clause as it whole, so it makes the most sense to put it before the word "expensive." Compare:

1. It's expensive, but it's not *really* expensive.
2. It's not expensive; in fact, it's *really* not expensive.

What makes this sound informal is the use of "really" as an intensifier; a more formal version would be:

> Just buy it. It's not expensive at all.

(You can't say "very not expensive," but that's a separate issue; I don't believe that such restrictions apply to the informal use of "really," as your example shows.)

Answer (score 0):

*It’s really not expensive* means *It’s truly not expensive.* So that part — assuming that’s what you mean — is good to go.

You are wise to correct the punctuation though, lest you be accused of comma splicing.